# How do I recode a character variable containing certain letters?

Tags: regex, recode

I have a dataframe in which I have merged rows according to certain variables. This has worked well, but I now have the problem that for some character variables, the values are duplicates.

I have two values, either "Con" or "Lab" and now have rows (which were merged) that now show "ConCon" or "LabLabLab".

My question is how do I recode these values? Ideally I need a command where a value containing "Lab" (e.g. "LabLabLabLab") is turned into Lab.

Any input would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Do you want this in R or Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In R:

```r
df <- data.frame(id = 1:5, party = c("Con", "ConCon", "LabLabLab", "LabLabLabLab", "ConConCon"))
df$party <- gsub("^(Con|Lab).*", "\\1", df$party)
df
##   id party
## 1  1   Con
## 2  2   Con
## 3  3   Lab
## 4  4   Lab
## 5  5   Con
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can't pass the "LabCon" case, you can do:

```
legal_words = ["Con", "Lab"]
to_change_words = ["Con", "ConCon", "LabLabLab", "LabLab", "Lab"]

for i,word in enumerate(to_change_words):
    for legal in legal_words:
        if legal in word:
            to_change_words[i] = legal

print(to_change_words)
```

And this will output

```
['Con', 'Con', 'Lab', 'Lab', 'Lab']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. However, the issue is that it goes from Lab being merged twice (LabLab) - all the way to being merged 30 times (LabLabLabLab...). I want to avoid having to write down each form which needs to be changed.

Comment: with this code you dont have to. I put those words as examples, if you have in "to_change_words" anything like "LabLabLabLabLabLabLabLab" it will work